# Bootstrap: Empty spaces on layout due text size

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I avoid empty spaces in this layout?

Each item is an article, that are inside of a div, but when the text of one of the items is bigger, it creates an empty space on the next row. The items are created dynamically so I cannot control the text size.

Is my first time with Bootstrap so any advice is welcome.

```
<div class="row margin-top-30">
     <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">...</article>
     <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">...</article>
     <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">...</article>
</div>
```

[Image with the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGO6L.png)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want it to be like? Hide the text? Show "..." ? Force text to be one line? Please elaborate

Comment: Your use of grid seems to be incorrect. For sm you are using a total of 18 cols and for md you are using 9 cols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution its for you that you have to use text overflow ellipsis with title of item then all box size will be equal text will be break in one line only so i thing it's better for you to use text overflow ellipsis title of the box. It is also compatible in browser.

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Maybe it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

On the second row of four elements, just add inline css:

```
style="margin-top:xxpx;"
```

Adjust the margin until the second row falls below the above row.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can solve ur problem by assigning min-height/max-height property of CSS. and also handle overflow in case u have problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your browser supports CSS3, you can use flexbox approach to solve this problem

```
<div class="row margin-top-30 flex-item-container" >
     <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">...</article>
     <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">...</article>
     <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">...</article>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-item-container{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

For more, refer https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/